# WindowsServer 2003 cmd check installed roles

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003, roles

I am creating a large batch script to check installed windows features (components) on a Windows 2003 server. I can not seem to figure out how to query server roles and display all sub-features of the role within the cmd shell. This is easy to do in Windows Server 2008 by simply using servermanager.exe or WMI, but I cannot figure out what program or cmd to use in Windows 2003. Windows Server 2003 has power shell installed, but it just seems like a glorified cmd shell in this Windows OS version. Does anyone know of a similar utility or cmd that can be used specifically on a Windows 2003 box? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this function

```
function Get-InstalledComponents($computer = '.') {
    $components_installed   = @();

    $reg_paths  = @('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'`
            + '\Setup\Oc Manager\Subcomponents');
    $reg_paths  += @('SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'`
            + '\Setup\Oc Manager\Subcomponents');

    $hkey   = 'LocalMachine';
    $reg    = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hkey, $computer);
    foreach ($reg_path in $reg_paths) {
        $reg_key    = $reg.OpenSubKey($reg_path);
        if ($reg_key -eq $null) {
            continue;
        }
        $names  = $reg_key.GetValueNames();

        foreach ($name in $names) {
            $value  = $reg_key.GetValue($name);
            if ($value -gt 0) {
                $components_installed += @($name);
            }
        }
        $reg_key.close();
    }
    $reg.close();

    if ($components_installed.count -lt 1) {
        trap { ;
        continue } $features = @(get-wmiobject -class 'Win32_ServerFeature' `
                    -computer $computer -erroraction 'Stop');

        foreach ($feature in $features) {
            $components_installed += @($feature.name);
        }
    }       

    return ($components_installed | sort);
}
```

Comment: See that the Remote Registry service on the computer is up and running.